# Use the main method of a .jar file inside a Matlab script

Tags: java, matlab, jar

I am trying to execute a method "main" from a Java class integrated into a JAR file. I tried to do it as follows:

```
javaclasspath 'file.jar';
javaMethod('main', 'JavaClass')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error using javaMethod
No class DemoClient can be located on the Java class path
```

Does anyone know how I can to integrate this JAR into my Matlab routine for carrying out an advanced Matlab operation.

Comment: You need to read this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/invoking-methods-on-java-objects.html#btodixk-1

Comment: You wrote `javaclasspath`. Are you sure you don't mean `javaaddpath`? Also, does your Java class have a package name?

Comment: I've set up MATLAB to call java functions in a netbeans project by using `javaaddpath('xxx\build\classes')` and then using `import xxx`. These are `.class` files but I'm sure a similar method would work for `.jar` files as well

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Regarding javaaddpath and javaclasspath, I have used both of them without results. About the second comment, I will try. At the moment what I have done is a system call within Matlab for running the command "java -jar"